# How to get the decimal part for float multiplication in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried float multiplication in Python 3.7 with 2 methods. Method 1 gives me the expected output with decimal value(4.995) but Method 2 gives me the rounded number only(5.0).

## **Method 1**

```
a=float(1.11)

b=float(4.5)

print(float(a*b))   
#  output is 4.995
```

## **Method 2**

```
x=5.0/4.5   # Output for x=1.11

a=float(x)

b=float(4.5)

print(float(a*b))   
#  output is 5.0
```

In my original code I want to calculate the x value as in **Method 2** (x=5.0/4.5) and I got the x value as **1.11** but if I use the x variable for float multiplication as in **Method 2** I got rounded number **5.0** rather than **4.995**. So how to get the decimal value for **Method 2** operation as like in **Method 1** ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: `5.0 / 4.5` is not `1.11`...

Comment: `(5/4.5) * 4.5 = 5` you are simply multiplying and dividing 5 by same value. Also python has automated typecasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second method doesn't give a rounded number, 5/4.5 = 1.111 repeating, and the way that this is stored in python is through binary replacement of the number, so in the four bits that are in a float it kind of looks like this, 
    0000000000000001.0001110001110001 
vs 1.11 which is stored more like so 
    0000000000000001.000111000010100011
so when doing multiplication it takes the bits and checks, sees that the top should be 1.11111111 repeating essentially and multiplies it to 5.0 note this isn't the full detailed explanation, it's more colloquial.

Comment: After doing round(x,2) in Method 2 I got the expected output.. Thank you very much Matt Deleeuw..